# In javascript, how can I search for "–" (en-dash)?

Tags: javascript, search

I am using javascript to search for text in an HTML page. One of the things I am looking for is lines the contain an "en-dash", HTML character – which in the HTML page looks like this (it is a list of items, separated with an en dash):

Item one
Item two
–
Item three

How do I search for it in Javascript? I've tried the following, which doesn't work:

itemList.search("–");
itemList.search("–");

Comment: You need to show us some code. We have no idea what `itemList` is. Also, `.search()` only works on strings, so if `itemList` is an object, it will throw an error.

Comment: itemList is a string . The code I have is as follows, and it doesn't find the en-dash, so the string is not made into a null string when it should (it works fine when itemList conatins a ":")  :   if ((itemList.search("&#8211;") != -1) || (itemList.search(":") != -1))
  itemList = '';

Answer (score 1):

There is a function indexOf. this will return the position of the character (or string) you search, return -1 of does not exist.

usage:

```
var str = "this is a dash - ...";
alert(str.indexOf('-'));
// or
alert(str.indexOf("\u2013")); // EN DASH unicode
```

If you don't know how to convert &#8211 to \u2013 you can use this function

```
function myUnescape(ampstr) {
  const span = document.createElement('SPAN');
  span.innerHTML = ampstr
  return span.textContent
}

myUnescape('&#8211') -> '-'
escape(myUnescape('&#8211')) -> '%u2013'
```

Comment: indexOf is not supported by all browsers

Comment: You are using a regular dash, that works fine. I am searching for an 
en-dash. which is showing up in the HTML code as a string of characters:  &#8211;

Answer (score 0):

Search is a function which is available on every String-Object. It returns the position of the match and if not found a -1.

So
"abc-de".search("-");
Returns 3 because it is on position 0123.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp